# Is there a way to make this numpy operation faster?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I am trying to copy raw image data from an API. The data is iterable or can use slicing (`[:]`). The image data is about 2000 x 2000 px. It is a grayscale float array, stored in 1D. This is what I am using now:

`imageData = np.fromiter(rawImageData, dtype=np.float32, count=width*height)`

It takes about 2-3 seconds to copy the data to a numpy array. Is there a faster way to copy/shape the data?

**Additional info:** I previously tried using `np.asarray`. It made it faster, but there was a conflict with threading where if tried to do anything in main thread while the operation was being done in a separate thread the program would crash.

Comment: depends on the image reading api. what do you use?

Comment: It is an internal API. The data is a 1D float array or gray-scale values.

Comment: Where you doing anything with that data in the main thread? Does your API expose the `__array__` interface?

Comment: No I was not doing anything with the data. The main thread runs the GUI and even if I tried to move the GUI, I would get a fatal python error (when the `np.asarray` operation was running). And I am not sure about `__array__` being exposed.

Comment: `np.array` had the same effect. I tried `Data = np.array(rawImageData[:], dtype=np.float32)
            imageData = np.reshape(Data, (height, width))` and it crashed when I moved the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

I am testing a .bmp image of 7200 by 4800 open with Pillow.

```
In [26]: %timeit np.array(im)
1 loops, best of 3: 222 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit np.asarray(im)
10 loops, best of 3: 156 ms per loop
```

Converting to float32 involves a copy, that takes some time, but saves memory:

```
In [39]: %timeit np.array(im, dtype=np.float32)
1 loops, best of 3: 444 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit np.asarray(im, dtype=np.float32)
1 loops, best of 3: 543 ms per loop
```

`fromiter` requires a 1D array, so let's grab only the R chanel (my image is in colour):

```
In [49]: %timeit np.fromiter(im.getdata(0), dtype=np.float32, count=7200*4800)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.49 s per loop
```

Ooops, there are your 2-3 seconds. The reason is that an iterator is a very opaque thing for numpy, that likes very structured things. Therefore, it has to infer on the fly what is going, and it is much less efficient. So, use one of the first two functions and see if they work.